# Is Python3 supported in DSX Local 1.1.1.00 (20170912_0351)?

Tags: dsx-local

When I open a notebook I get below warning in DSX Local 1.1.1.00 (20170912_0351) x86_64:

I couldn't find a kernel matching Python 3. Please select a kernel:
Python2 with DSX Spark
and
Python2 with ML

Does this mean that we don't yet support Python3?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x is not yet supported on DSX Local.
Please stay tuned for newer version.

Thanks